# Push local merge to Gerrit Code Review

Tags: git, merge, gerrit

I'm relative new to Git/Gerrit. 
I had to solve a bug for a customer on an old version of one of our software. I reset my local Git to the commit corresponding to this version, than created a new branch (let's call it **C**), solved the bug and commited the change on my local new branch. Finally I switched to Master and merged the new branch **C** into this. So the situation was this:

```
c1-> .. ->cx->cy (version of the custormer)->..->cz (Master/Origin)----->ck (merge commit)
               |                                                        ^
               ->cn (branch C) (bug fix)--------------------------------|
```

I use Eclipse as editor with eGit to manage Git commit. So I pushed to Gerrit my repository. I expected that only the commit **ck** was pushed (it is the only new commit on the Master branch) but instead also **cn** was pushed.
I abbandoned **cn** on Gerrit and **ck** was marked as +2 and submitted, but now it's is in pending status, I imagine because it's marked as depending on the abbandoned **cn** commit.

I want to merge **cn** on the Gerrit master, how can I do this? What is the correct way to behave in a situation like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you push your merge commit `ck` for review, you are also pushing `cn` for review because it is not yet in the repository.  Gerrit creates a new 'change' for each commit that does not yet exist.

There are two ways to work around this.

1. Push `cn` as it is (based on `cy`) and then when it's merged Gerrit will create the merge commit for you (assuming you use the 'Merge if necessary' strategy).
2. Rebase `cn` onto the latest head of the master branch and push it again.

To go with option 1, simply restore the version of `cn` that you abandoned, then review and merge it.

For option 2, restore the change as in option 1 and then either rebase it locally and push again, or rebase it with the 'Rebase' button on the UI.

In both cases, the merge commit `ck` can be abandoned.